# how to achieve this design in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I want to make a design similar to this but I don't know how to achieve this design?[image]

Comment: Check out this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78062594/19269162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stepper class or create your own widgets for this.
Check out the following code for implementation:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int currentStep = 0;
  List<Map<String, String>> list = [
    {
      'date': '09.30AM',
      'title': 'Order Placed',
      'sub': 'Your order #212423 was placed for delivery'
    },
    {'date': '09.35AM', 'title': 'Pending', 'sub': 'Your order is pending for confirmation'},
    {'date': '09.55AM', 'title': 'Confirmed', 'sub': 'Your order is confirmed'},
    {
      'date': '10.30AM',
      'title': 'Processing',
      'sub': 'Your product is processing to de'
    },
    {'date': '10.45AM', 'title': 'Delivered', 'sub': 'Product delivered to you'},
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListView.separated(
            itemCount: list.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return currentStep >= index ? Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                    child: Text(list[index]['date']!),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 25),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      index < list.length - 1 ? Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.green
                      ) : Container(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Text(list[index]['title']!, style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),),
                          Flexible(child: Text(list[index]['sub']!)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ) : Container();
            }, separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return const SizedBox(height: 10);
          },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              currentStep += 1;
            });
          }, child: const Text('Change Step'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/order_tracker) package for tracker.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
class TrackerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrackerDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TrackerDemo> createState() => _TrackerDemoState();
}

class _TrackerDemoState extends State<TrackerDemo> {
  ///this TextDto present in a package add data in this dto and set in a list.

  List<TextDto> orderList = [
    TextDto("Your order has been placed", "Fri, 25th Mar '22 - 10:47pm"),
    TextDto("Seller ha processed your order", "Sun, 27th Mar '22 - 10:19am"),
    TextDto("Your item has been picked up by courier partner.",
        "Tue, 29th Mar '22 - 5:00pm"),
  ];

  List<TextDto> shippedList = [
    TextDto("Your order has been shipped", "Tue, 29th Mar '22 - 5:04pm"),
    TextDto("Your item has been received in the nearest hub to you.", null),
  ];

  List<TextDto> outOfDeliveryList = [
    TextDto("Your order is out for delivery", "Thu, 31th Mar '22 - 2:27pm"),
  ];

  List<TextDto> deliveredList = [
    TextDto("Your order has been delivered", "Thu, 31th Mar '22 - 3:58pm"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Order Tracker Demo"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: OrderTracker(
          status: Status.shipped,// Tracker status
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          inActiveColor: Colors.grey[300],
          orderTitleAndDateList: orderList,
          shippedTitleAndDateList: shippedList,
          outOfDeliveryTitleAndDateList: outOfDeliveryList,
          deliveredTitleAndDateList: deliveredList,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If it's helpful to you, then accept the answer and don't forget to upvote.